# Importing AD Users in to SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, user-accounts

I need a help in import active directory users in to SharePoint online. So that the authentication will be done with imported users on SharePoint online.

Please help me with procedure to integrate/import on premise AD to SharePoint online.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an enterprise-level “E Plan” subscription, you can use Active Directory Synchronization. This lets you use your existing Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) infrastructure to grant access to SharePoint Online resources.

You can also enable the Single Sign-On (SSO) functionality. This is powered by Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS). SSO lets your users seamlessly access SharePoint Online resources without re-entering their credentials. SSO gives you additional capabilities, as well. You can manage account policies and access restrictions through centralized Active Directory administrative tools.

For the whole procedure you can refer:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh395478.aspx

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/migrate-to-office-365-configure-sharepoint-to-use-active-directory

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2013/05/07/office-365-configuring-dirsync-and-single-sign-on-with-adfs.aspx